# Java: Receive files of multiple types

Tags: java, inputstream, fileoutputstream

I didn't see a similar question and I apologize if this question is not specific enough.

I will start out with that I am new to Java, I coded in it about 10+ years ago (basic stuff), but don't remember any of it.  I am working on a program that listens on a socket and can receive multiple data types, I.E. Text, receive FTP file, receive http post file.  I would like to be able analyze the incoming data type and then process each type differently. I have found several articles on how to do everything on separate ports, but wanted to find out if there is a better way to do so.

The problem I have with some of the solutions is that I don't want a full ftp or http server, I just want to receive files via ftp put or http post.

Edit:  When I say I don't need a server, I mean I don't need to handle anything outside of receiving the file.

Additional Clarity:  Take something simple like this(example purposes only)

```
BufferedReader br = null;
    in = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
while (true) {
  String input;
  while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(input);
  }
  in.close();
}
```

That will just print whatever text I send the listener.  I'm wondering if there is a way to check the input stream for type.  This might be beyond my skills, but would like someplace to read up on it.  Everything I read is type(FTP, HTTP, custom client) specific, so ideally I would check the input stream and then do something.

```
if(socket.getInputStream() == HTTP || FTP){
 //receive file
}
else if(stream == text){
  //parse text
}
else { //unsupported format }
```

or

```
String streamType = getStreamType(inputStream) //returns input stream type.
```

Up til this point, my coding experience has all been what to do with data I get.  This is my first time working with sockets and listeners.

Thanks

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to do here. You want to receive a HTTP POST without a HTTP server ? Unless your question has more clarity, I doubt you'll receive any helpful answers.

Comment: Show out what have you tried so far

Comment: Listening on a socket, you receive data as plain byte stream, so you should think about some kind of protocol to identify the file being received first, otherwise you only have a bytestream and don't know what to do with it.

Comment: @Desolator - I haven't coded anything outside of a basic socket listen and examples of the different types(Apache's ftp server and httpcore).

Comment: @Desolator-oops, hit wrong enter to finish. worked with the different examples of the different servers. Apache's ftp server and httpcore stuff.

Background-The originally program just receive plain text and then there was a separate ftp/http server application that received files.  My thought was that it might be better if the java app could handle it all, without the need for the separate applications.

I'll accept if this isn't practical. I just couldn't find anything on Google, but I blame this on my lack of search skills.  Everything was protocol specific.

Comment: @Smutje - This is were I'm having a issues I think.  My thought was that I could analyze the stream, then from the client side perspective there is no change.  If I understand you, I would need the client to tell me what they are sending first?